# What is the easiest way to update perl on Ubuntu 8.04LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, perl

I have an app that currently runs on perl5.8 that I would like to upgrade to perl5.10, if not 5.11.

The only problem is we run Ubuntu LTS everywhere that I'd need to deploy this to.

From what I've read installing perl 5.10 on top of perl 5.8 can lead to problems with loading the wrong version of modules among other confusion.

Is there any recommended way to get to modern perl on LTS?

Comment: 5.11.1 is development version - don't use it in production. Best version to upgrade is 5.10.1.

Comment: I think there was a similar question on http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options: Compile a local version and put it in `/opt` or `/usr/local/`, or backport the perl packages from a later release. Unless you've got experience creating Debian packages, the former is going to be easier; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398221/how-do-you-manage-perl-modules-on-linux/398397#398397) and some of the others to that question have more details. In particular, give the perl 5.10 binary a unique name like `perl5.10.0` so you have to explicitly call it and the system packages don't run it by mistake.

Comment: That's how to do it. +1 especially for mentioning giving the new perl binary a different name to avoid clashing with the system perl.

Comment: Putting it in a different directory, not on the customary local path setup, is also giving it a different (fully qualified) name.  E.g. - /usr/local/perl5/bin/perl or something similar.  Of course, scripts should be using a "#!" line (with absolute path), rather than relying on the path to stumble upon something, possibly nefarious.